# How to install WAMP with multiple hosts on a non-standard port, over a FIOS connection?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wampserver

I am trying to upgrade my server on a home network, supporting a few personal and club websites.

*The issue:*

- An aging *legacy* server running in an internal network (that includes several personal use computers). The server supports two public domains, under a single IP address.
      
   For example: `example1.org` and `example2.net`, under IP address `170.101.32.5`

  The legacy server supports several custom-built server-side applications that **are** still being used. Conversion of these apps (to PHP) will take a few months.

  The internet connection is via FIOS (static IP address).

*The goal:*

- Upgrade to a *new* (Apache/mySql/PHP capable) server.

  Since app conversion will take several months, a staged upgrade will be used.

  Thus: during the upgrade process both machines (legacy and new) should be operational

Note that:

- The legacy server does not run Windows or Linux; and is not running Apache.

  The apps are built using older languages (not PHP, and not .NET).

  Hence simply swapping in a new machine won't work

After several hours of testing, I provide an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I used  Windows 10 PC with WAMP version 3.2.6_x64 (Apache 2.4.51)
The  *legacy* server will continue to use port 80, and the *new*  server will use port 8080

The following lists the several steps I used to achieve the desired solution.
For now I kept it simple: IPV4 support, http: (no SSL support). None of the steps are complicated, but getting them all right took some time.

#### Step 1 : Modifying Windows

The following assumes that you were able to successfully install Windows, with a stable connection to the internet.
That uses DHCP to obtain an internal IP addresss.
And that you installed WAMP, and that it works locally.

> ```
> For example: `http://127.0.0.1/` will display server information (using a  phpInfo() type of format).
> ```

##### 1a: Assign a static IP address to the new server using  Windows *Settings*

<kbd>Network and Internet</kbd>  -> <kbd>ethernet</kbd>
Click on box that appears -- could have text `Network connected`

Set network profile to <kbd>public</kbd>

Then scroll down to `ip settings`, and click <kbd>edit</kbd>.

Several input boxes appear ...

In the first box:

- change to <kbd>Manual</kbd>

Several new input boxes are shown:

- `IPV4`: turn <kbd>on</kbd>.  For now, I did not turn on IPV6
- `IP address`:  A static internal address. For example: <kbd>192.168.1.4</kbd>.
  This static address is used in the *modifying router* step below
- `Subnet prefix length`: Set to <kbd>24</kbd>.
  Note that I did not need to specify a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask.
- `Gateway`: could be <kbd>192.168.1.1</kbd>   -- I did not change this field.
- `Prefered DNS`: I entered the DNS that associated with my FIOS account.
  But `192.168.1.1` (the default) also worked.

And then <kbd>Save</kbd>

##### 1b: Windows firewall modification.

Hint: to find it type "firewall" in the search box, and select "Windows Defender Firewall"

- Guest or public networks: set to  <kbd>connected</kbd>
- Under <kbd>Advanced settings</kbd> -> <kbd>inbound rules</kbd> -> <kbd>new rule</kbd>
  `type of rule`: <kbd>port</kbd>

> - `apply to`: <kbd>tcp</kbd>
> - `All ports?` Specific ports: <kbd>8080</kbd>
> - Select the `Allow the connection`radio button,
> - `When does this rule apply`: check all 3 boxes (or maybe just check `public` box)
> - `name` and `description` as you see fit

- Click `Finish`

  This required clicking <kbd>Next</kbd> a few times.
  After `Finish`, the name of this new rule will appear in the list of inbound rules.

> ```
>   If you want to enable ping, under the existing inbound rules find and enable
>     File and Printer Sharing --  Echo Request (ICMPv4-IN)
>   I enabled both the <i>Domain</i> and  <i>Private. </i> versions of this rule.
> ```

You might have to reboot Windows after these changes. Make sure it works (that the internet connection is stable)

*Notes:*

- Since Microsoft is annoying about constantly changing the Windows setting menu structure, you may have to search for some of these.
  The <kbd>windows search box</kbd> can be helpful.
- Hint: from a windows command prompt, `C:>ipconfig /all`
  will show current IP settings (such as the Default Gateway and DNS Server).
- As of March 2022 WAMP (version 3.2.6_x64) installation required installing several Microsoft redistributables.
  The links are listed on the Wamp installation screens. Downloading and installing them was tedious but not difficult
- As suggested elsewhere, you need to be sure nothing conflicts with your http ports.  For example, Skype or IIS.
  See  [Upgraded to Windows 10  ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713586/upgraded-to-windows-10-and-now-wamp-wont-work)
  for some useful tips (on using netstat -aon)

#### Step 2: Modifying the router

These details are specific to my internet setup: static Verizon Fios, using a 2 year old Fios-G1100  router.
I logon to it from an internal PC using 192.168.1.1

##### 2a: set up a Port Forwarding Rule

<kbd>Advanced</kbd>  -> <kbd>Network Setting</kbd> -> <kbd>Port Forwarding Rules</kbd> ->  <kbd>Add</kbd>

- `Service Name`: <kbd>httpAlt</kbd>. You can use whatever word you want, it will be used in the next step
- `Service description`: something descriptive
- Click on `Add Server Ports`

> - `Protocol`:  <kbd>TCP</kbd>
> - `Source ports`: <kbd>Any</kbd>
> - `Destination ports`: <kbd>Single</kbd>
> - In the input box that appears: <kbd>8080</kbd>

- Click `Apply` (save these specifications)
- Click `Apply` (save this rule)

The list of *Port Forwarding Rules* will now contain a `httpAlt` row (or whatever  `Service Name`  you chose).

##### 2b: Assign a Port Forwarding Rule to an internal IP address

o back to `Main`, click on <kbd>Port Forwarding</kbd>.

- Under <kbd>Create new port forwarding rule</kbd>:

> - In the `Select IP from menu` dropdown menu
> - Chose the <kbd>static IP address</kbd> you assigned to the new machine (using the above setup: `192.168.1.4`)
>   *Thus:*  you need to set the  static IP address (on the *new* server) BEFORE this step --the router looks for existing IP addresses (in the local network)!
> - In the `Application to forward` dropdown menu
>   Select <kbd>httpAlt</kbd> (or whatever `Service Name` you specified above)

- Click the `Add` button

##### 2c: To avoid possible DHCP clashes with the new (and old) server (that both use static internal IP addresses)

<kbd>Advanced</kbd>  -> `Routing  ..`  <kbd>IPv4 address distribution</kbd>

In the row with DHCP Server in the **Service** column: click <kbd>Edit</kbd>

- Set the Start IPV4 address. Say to <kbd>192.168.1.6</kbd>
- Note that the static IP address assigned to the new server ( `192.168.1.4`)
  is less than the Start IPV4 address `192.168.1.6`
- Click `Apply`
- Click `Close`

#### Step 3) Modifying Wamp and Windows configurartion files

I installed wamp under `D:\wamp64`.  So if WAMP is installed somewhere else, change `D:\wamp64` accordingly.

##### 3a) Edit apache conf file

This can be found at `D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf`   where `2.4.51` is the apache version installed.

- *Changing the <Directory >*

  Find the block that begins with `<Directory />` and change to:

  ```
     <Directory>
     # AllowOverride none
     #  Require all denied
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     </Directory>
  ```

> If you do **not** do this (if  you do **not** have an `Allow from all` or similar line) -- 403 responses will be returned.
> I assume this can also be  set by using `.htaccess` files?

- *Changing ports Apache will watch*

  Find the `Listen` line and add

  `Listen 8080`

  Note that a preexisting `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`  means *all ip addresss using port 80*.

  It seems that `Listen 8080` is a shortcut for `Listen 0.0.0.0:8080`  ?
- *Make sure the following lines are enabled* (do not start with `#`)

  ```
   LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```

##### 3b: Edit httpd-vhosts.conf

```
Add to `d:\wamp64\bin\apache2.4.51\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example1.org
  ServerAlias example1.org *.example1.org
  ServerAdmin admin@example1.org
   DocumentRoot "D:/www1"
  <Directory "D:/www1">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example2.net
  ServerAlias example2.net *.example2.net
  ServerAdmin admin@example2.net
   DocumentRoot "D:/wwwOther"
  <Directory "D:/wwwOther">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Notes:*

- CAUTION: you **must** use `/` (not `\`) in DocumentRoot and Directory!! I wasted 45 minutes because I forgot this.
- `D:/www1` should contain the content for the example1.org domain
- `D:/wwwOther` should contain the  content for the example2.net domain
- As noted in  [ServerName directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername): `*.a.b`  means *all subdomains of a.b*

Note: something like the following may already exist. I left it in (to support local testing):

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
     <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require local
    </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

##### 3c: Edit Windows host file

For ease of internal testing, one can add lines to `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
This will resolve the ipname to an ip address -- its a *check this first* dns. But it might
[not work with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842319/firefox-not-honoring-hosts-file).

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.4 myStuffLocal.org
```

Note that `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. can only be modified by an administrator.
I used Notepad in *admin* mode (RMB on the Notepad icon).

Restart Wamp, or to be sure restart Windows.
Then go to some other computer (perhaps one **not** on the same internal network) and try it out.